# C/C++ conversion of double to a fixed point with minimum number of non-zero digits

Tags: c, double

multiple fixed-point decimal numbers are mapped to the same double value.
For example:

```
double d1 = 132.24;
double d2 =  132.24000000000001;
```

d1 and d2 have the same binary value.

When converting d1 (or d2, they have the same value) to string using ostream with 14 digits of precision, it is converted to: 132.24000000000001 .

Is there a way/library that supports conversion from **double->string**, where the string is the fixed-point value with a minimal number of non-zero digits and that is a valid conversion ? i.e. in this case converting d1 to a string will return 132.24000000000000 (shown with 14 digits precision)

Comment: This precise problem was the subject of the ["Dragon4" and "Grisu3" algorithms](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2011/06/29/here-be-dragons-advances-in-problems-you-didnt-even-know-you-had/). It's more-or-less solved, though improvements are still possible.

Comment: This is how floating point works! Please see [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: the float/double type of variables cannot represent certain/many values exactly.  Your question just happens to hit upon one of those many values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library  https://github.com/floitschG/double-conversion 
provides the DoubleToStringConverter::DoubleToAscii method with the SHORTEST option:
"SHORTEST: produce the least amount of digits for which the internal identity requirement is still satisfied."

Thanks a lot to iwillnotexist-idonotexist for pointing me to the right direction.